# How to make 'redirected webpage' accesible inside LAN?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

We have our company's website `https://www.website1.com` that is hosted on HostGator and that was inaccessible only from the inside LAN. I added a new Host `A` record in DNS for `www` which points to the public IP address of the web server and now the website is accessible on the LAN too.

Now our developers created another website for our second company: `https://www.website2.com`.

In this case what they did is this: when end-users type in the browser: `https://www.website2.com` - this domain redirects end-users to a menu of our first website with this path: `https://www.website1.com/company2/company-profile`.

The second website works fine from outside networks except from the inside LAN! `https://www.website2.com` is not accessible on the inside LAN and the redirection to the `https://www.website1.com/company2/company-profile` does not happen!

I tried adding another Host `A` record in DNS for `www` which points to the public IP address of `https://www.website2.com` but nothing happens!

Answer (score 0):

You, maybe, need to add the "www A record" to the domain *website2*.
There may be other things in the way, but this is the first that comes to mind.